# Remove structured data with JavaScript doesn't work for Google bot

Tags: googlebot, structured-data, rdfa

I have an e-commerce subscription where I can only add additional JavaScript for the pages. Since Google Search Console gives warning for the generated HTML I decided first to fix, then to remove schema but on my tests it is now clear to me that google doesn't respect DOM manipulation. What are my other options if any?

The error which is displayed on search console is **Missing field "itemListElement"**

Here is the test code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul vocab="https://schema.org/" typeof="BreadcrumbList">
        <li>
            <a href="/" title="Anasayfa"><span>Homepage</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h1 property="name">All Products <span>21 results</span></h1>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <script>
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll("[vocab]");

        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
            elems[i].removeAttribute("vocab");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works fine for me. Maybe it's because your not removing the typeof attribute.

Comment: Removing vocab actually is enough but even if I remove typeof from the ul I still got error: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=https%3A%2F%2Finnovacube.com%2Ftest.htm

Comment: The structured data testing tool does not truly render pages and execute JavaScript like google. Try it in the Rich Results Test or the GSC Live Test. It's happy with just vocab being removed. I